# UnsupportedOperationException when trying to add instances of a child class to a list in Grails 2.3.9

Tags: grails

I have 3 child domains that extends a parent domain like so:

```
Dog extends Animal
Cat extends Animal
Snake extends Animal
```

In one of my services, I have a `List<Animal>` and I'm trying to add objects(of class dog, cat and snake) to it like so:

```
List<Animal> animals = Dogs.findAllByBreed("someBreed")
             animals << Cats.findAllBySomething("something")
animals = [animals].flatten()
```

It works brilliant on run-app and I didn't get any errors. However, on test-app I get `UnsupportedOperationException` which I find a bit odd.

Can someone tell what is wrong? I was thinking that it should be possible since Dog and Cat are both animals. I am supposed to update values that are common to them but the test just fails. Below is the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at ...
```

Comment: Do you use this service in test? Possibly you had make some mocking incorrect

Comment: Yes, the error appears on test. I changed my implementation and just used different lists instead of using one list for all three because I couldn't pass the test. It must be the mocking, or maybe grails just hates me.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure, that `Dog ---> Dogs.findByBreed("someBreed")` works? I've never seen this plural notation before...

Anyway, I'd suggest to wrap the original list into an `ArrayList`

```
List animals = new ArrayList( Dog.findAllByBreed("someBreed") )
     animals.addAll Cat.findAllBySomething("something")
```

Comment: oops sorry, yeah it's findAll. Was typing away on my phone... :\

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
List<Animal> animals = Dogs.findAllByBreed("someBreed")
animals << Cats.findAllBySomething("something")
animals = [animals].flatten()
```

Try this:

```
List<Animal> animals = Dogs.findAllByBreed("someBreed")
animals += Cats.findAllBySomething("something")
```

When you use `animals << Cats.findAllBySomething("something")` you are adding a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Animal>`, which is not valid.  You should be able to add `Cat` instances to a `List<Animal>` but you can't add a `List` to a `List<Animal>`.  When you use `+=` you are adding the elements of a `List<Cat>` to a `List<Animal>`, which is probably what you wanted.